# Word for "increasing someone's doubts about something"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Yesterday I was trying to say that *something increased my doubts about ABC*, but couldn't really come up with any verb other than "increase", so I dropped what I was saying. I know that **"dispel"** means "to finish someone's doubts and looking up its antonyms turned up **engender**, but I think it is a bit formal and I have never heard it. **Engender** means *cause or give rise to (a feeling, situation, or condition)*, can I use it to mean "increase someone's doubts"?

> XYZ **engendered** my doubts about ABC

Is this something native speakers would use in daily conversations? If not, what would be another equivalent to mean "it increased my doubts about ABC"

Comment: If it *engendered* them you had none before. You could say XYZ added to your doubts about ABC. I prefer that to 'increased', though I'm not sure why. Why did you want to replace it?

Comment: You could say: *XYZ **cast further doubt** on ABC*.

Comment: *Engendered* is a good word, but "engendered *my* doubts" sounds strange.  [Google Ngrams finds "engendered doubts" but not "engendered *my* doubts".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=engendered+doubts%2Cengendered+my+doubts&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cengendered%20doubts%3B%2Cc0)